# My download.php script sends a corrupt file

Tags: php, file, download

I am having difficulty working out my download.php script. The customer gets a unique download link generated from my database and when they click it on it is meant to send them the file from my server. Only in my case the zip file is always corrupt and bigger then the original file. Original file is 68KB and the downloaded file ends up being 90KB.

Here is my code that sends the file to the browser:

```
<?php 
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT transaction_id FROM slx_jomsocial_plugin_orders WHERE (transaction_id ='". $tx ."' and unique_code='". $token ."')");
$rowCount = $wpdb->num_rows;
if($rowCount==1){
$name="Unzip_First_Video_Embedding.zip";
$file_url=$actual_link."/jomsplugins/".$name;   
header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name); 
readfile($file_url);
       echo "<h1>Thank you ".$name=$_SESSION['s_name']." For downloading the plugins.</h1><br />";
}else{
       echo "<h1>You are not permitted to downlaod, Please purchase plugin first.</h1> <br /><div style=\"margin-left: 25%;margin-top: 1%;\"><a href=\"http://code-grab.com/\" title=\"Code-grab\">Click Here</a></div>";
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

I have been experimenting with the script but still my files come out corrupted (Unzipping them gives a .cpgz file). Here is my current script now:

```
<?php 

$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT transaction_id FROM slx_jomsocial_plugin_orders WHERE (transaction_id ='". $tx ."' and unique_code='". $token ."')");
$rowCount = $wpdb->num_rows;
if($rowCount==1){

// set example variables
$filename = "Unzip_First_Video_Embedding.zip";
$filepath = $actual_link."/jomsplugins/";

// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_end_flush();
ob_clean();
flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
ob_clean();
flush();
exit;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you can't do the echo "<h1>Thank you "..., because that is appended to the ZIP file. Simply remove this line. However, that doesn't yet explain many extra KB in the file. There is another problem.

Comment: I'd remove the `echo` command and also add a `Content-lenght` header.

Comment: You're passing a URL to readfile(), e.g. http://.... . Is this your intention? It looks wrong to me on first glance, because in this scenario, readfile() is usually used to read from the server's file system rather than from a network URL.

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different ways to do this, either generate a URL and forward the user on to that (I would guess this would be easier), or read the file from the local disk, not a URL.

Comment: @JamieKitson So should I change this line    $file_url=$actual_link."/jomsplugins/".$name; to this? $file_url="../jomsplugins/".$name;